# Run python script from python using different python

Tags: python, env

I have a software that has python 2.5.5. I want to send a command that would start a script in python 2.7.5 and then proceed with the script.

I tried using

```
#!python2.7.5
```

and http://redsymbol.net/articles/env-and-python-scripts-version/

But I cant get it to work...
In my python 2.5.5 I can execute script as 
execfile("c:/script/test.py")

The problem is that the 2.7.5 has a module comtypes + few other. I dont know how to install it for my 2.5.5 so I'm trying to start a separate script and run it under python27. Now another reason why I want it its because I want to take the load off program. I have 2 heavy tasks to perform. The second task is the one that need comptypes so sending it to external shell/app would do perfect trick. Is there a way to do it ?

I wish I could just type run("C:/Python27/python.exe % C:/script/test,py")

Thanks, bye.

Little update. I try to run

```
import os 
os.system("\"C:\Python27\python.exe\" D:\test\runTest.py")
```

But I'm getting a quick pop up and close window saying that 
Import Error : no module named site...
This works if I run from external shell but not from here :(

So I've tried another approach this time to add modules to python... in any case I run this :

```
import os 
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/python27")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/libs")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/logging")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/ctypes")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/DLLs")    
import PyQt4
print PyQt4   
import comtypes
import logging
```

but it crashes with C error...
Runtime Error :
Program: c:\Pr...
R6034
An application has made attempt to load the C runtime library incorectly.
blablabla....

How can I import it ? Maybe if I can import it I can run it directly from my app rather than starting separate python...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ctypes import *
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Another update to isseu

so I run now

```
import os
os.system("start cmd {D:\test\runTest.py}")
```

now this works and he open CMD with c:\Python27 as directory but he dont run the file... any hitns how to fix it?

Comment: `python2.7 script.py` should work.

Comment: Hay Blender ! could you maybe type in full line of the code? atm I get error...  File "<string>", line 1
    python2.7 script.py
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: From your console, not in the shebang.

Comment: Now you totally lost me :( you mean  import os
os.system("start cmd {python2.7 D:\test\runTest.py}")

Answer (score 0):

Use "raw" strings so that you don't need to escape as much; I think the backslashes are what was breaking your code since backslash is considered an escape character *except* in raw strings.

Also, use the `subprocess` module. It makes it easy to avoid manually making a safe command string (the module takes care of that for you). All you need to do is pass it a list of arguments.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
import subprocess 

proc = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Python27\python.exe", r"D:\test\runTest.py"])

# then either do this
proc.wait()  # wait until the process finishes

# or this
while True:
    # NOTE: do something else here

    # poll the process until it is done
    if proc.poll() is not None:
        break  # break out of loop
```

See subprocess docs for Python 2 [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). Be sure to check if a feature was added after Python 2.5 (the 2.5 docs aren't available online anymore AFAIK).

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that you tried to use the Python 2.7 libraries and modules in your 2.5 code. This probably won't work due to new features added after 2.5. But it got me thinking how you might be able to make 2.7 work.

It may be that your Python2.7 install can't find its libraries; this is probably why you get the error `Import Error : no module named site`. You can do something like the above and modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable *before* starting the subprocess, like this:

```
import os
import subprocess 

paths = [r"C:\python27", r"C:\python27\libs", r"C:\python27\Lib\site-packages", r"C:\python27\DLLs"]
paths += os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', '').split(os.pathsep)

env27 = dict(os.environ)
env27['PYTHONPATH'] = os.pathsep.join(paths)

proc = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Python27\python.exe", r"D:\test\runTest.py"], env=env27)
```

Comment: An explanation on the downvote would be appreciated so that I know what to improve with my answer, or how to improve future answers.